# How to use lookup operator icontains in raw query of django mongodb engine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query, django-mongodb-engine

I am using `django-mongodb-engine`

Here, I used `MongoDBManager` to use a raw query.

```
class NameInfo(models.Model)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Abc(models.Model):
    name = EmbeddedModelField('NameInfo')
    objects = MongoDBManager()

Abc.objects.raw_query({'name.firstname.contains':'j'})
```

The last line is not working as expected. So, how can I use the `contains` lookup type on embedded fields?

***If there is another workaround not using `MongoDBManager` that would also be acceptable.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB terms this is a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operation, so you issue in "raw" like this:

```
Abc.objects.raw_query({ "name.firstname": { "$regex": "j" } })
```

Note that the objects returned are not the model objects from your class definitions but simply raw python objects.

Comment: Perfect Answer!  The first query is working, second one is not, because i am using django-mongodb-engine, not mongoengine.

Comment: @jatin Sorry I'll strip that. On autopilot as a mongoengine user myself. Should have read your tags.

Comment: Hey! We don't use semicolon in Python ;)